# How do I install tracking code on marketing client websites?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook

I'm a marketer and wish to enable a tracking mechanism on my clients' websites so that both they and I have data demonstrating the effectiveness of the ads. These ads are real-world ads, like billboards.

I know it's fairly easy to set up a facebook pixel or a google analytics tracking on any website. However, this data would be client owned, and not accessible by me. So how do I create my own "pixel" and use it to track the effectiveness of a particular campaign which uses a very specific landing page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple Google analytics tracking codes onto your pages. You're allowed to have multiple scripts with "create" and "send" with two different UA-# trackers. This way they can have their own tracking, and you can have yours.

Google Analytics also allows multiple email addresses to view the analytics data. You can add emails in Admin->User Management.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a url to a pixel that is hosted on a server whose logs can be accessed by you. Each time a user lands on the page, it will be recorded in the access-logs of your that web server. Then parse the log files and extract relevant data using regex. Or use something like papertrailapp.com.

But,

If it's only a matter of accessing the analytics data of the website, you can have the client grant you read-only access to their Google Analytics account. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager is useful for this.

The client would need to include the Google Tag Manager code on each page on their site (as you would do with GA) and give you access to the account.

You would then be able to add new tracking pixels/code via Google Tag Manager without asking the client to install the individual code themselves.